# Неправильно читается файл

Tags: c#

Всем привет скажите, вот я попробовал в консоле сделать читалку моего файла:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\errorbleat.fat", FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

foreach (char ch in br.ReadChars(100500))
{
    Console.Write(ch.ToString());
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Она всё правильно читает, но это консоль, и я решил сделать такое на winForms, так вот там проблема, есть контрол richTextBox - в него всё должно записываться.... но беда, когда я делаю так:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fs = new FileStream("D:\\errorbleat.fat", FileMode.Open);

    br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    foreach (char ch in br.ReadChars(100500))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = ch.ToString();
    }

    timer1.Start();
}
```

У меня почему-то читает только 1 символ, а когда делаю так

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    fs = new FileStream("D:\\errorbleat.fat", FileMode.Open);

    br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    foreach (char ch in br.ReadChars(100500))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text **+**= ch.ToString();
    }

    timer1.Start();
}
```

То он до бесконечности мне выводит одни и те же записи... как сделать, чтобы он вывел всё, что лежит в моём файле ОДИН раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 richTextBox1.LoadFile(new FileStream("D:\\errorbleat.fat", FileMode.Open),RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
```

Так не подходит?

Comment: Ага, спасибо.